# AuthKeyDuplicatedError telethon

Tags: telegram, telethon

With the code below I have been connected to the telegram using telethon for about one year!

```
client = TelegramClient(
        SESSION,
        API_ID,
        API_HASH
    )
client.connect()
# the rest of my code
```

Yesterday when I want to connect to my session with the code I got this error:

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.AuthKeyDuplicatedError: An auth key with the same ID was already generated
```

The error does not tell anymore and in [the doc](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) there is no more description about this error message. How can I retrieve my session?

Comment: have you ported your application to another server? (or at least have you changed your IP and system configurations?)

Comment: and another way to produce this error is to run 2 instances of the same session in separate locations simultaneously(or at least with a small difference in their connection time to TG)

Comment: @tashakori yes I have changed my IP. How can but this changing was not the first change. I had changed the IP many times with no error. I think the problem was the second you mentioned. How can I correct it?

Comment: do you have an access to the phone number you're using for the telethon client?

Comment: Unfortunately no. because they were virtual numbers. But I access one of them only. How can I fix that one?

Comment: First, make sure that no Telethon session instances are running on your server(s)(at least for those you have access to). Second, you can kill that session manually(in "active session" part of telegram applications e.g. android). 
third, delete .session files from your server. fourth, sign in to your client in the server again.

Comment: when do you get this error? do you get that when you're creating TelegramClient instance or when calling a specific API?

Comment: I get this error exactly when I call `connect`

Comment: So, as far as I know, I afraid that you can't do anything for other clients that you don't have access to their numbers(or any other active sessions in other applications).

Answer (score 4):

one of the ways to produce this error is to run 2 instances of the same session in separate locations simultaneously(or at least with a small difference in their connection time to TG)

if you have access to those phone numbers(or any other active sessions of them e.g. Android app), you can do the below procedure, otherwise as far as I know, I afraid that you can't do anything for other compromised clients that you don't have access to their numbers(or any other active sessions in other applications):

First, make sure that no Telethon session instances are running on your server(s)(at least for those you have access to). Second, you can kill that session manually(in "active session" part of telegram applications e.g. Android). third, delete ".session" files from your server. fourth, sign in to your client in the server again.